# Why is blade file not show anything although code are correct in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I installed Laravel 8 and set up a blade file.
I moved resources folders css, js, and bootstrap files to public folder and loaded from blade file.

This is master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"><script/>
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"><script/>

</head>
<body>
 @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

This is welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">                    
            <div class="panel panel-info" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
                    </div>     

                    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                        <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>
                            
                        <form id="loginform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                    
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="" placeholder="username or email">                                        
                                    </div>
                                
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
                                    </div>
                                    

                                
                            <div class="input-group">
                                      <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                          <input id="login-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                                        </label>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                                      <a id="btn-login" href="#" class="btn btn-success">Login  </a>
                                      <a id="btn-fblogin" href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                        <div style="border-top: 1px solid#888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                            Don't have an account! 
                                        <a href="#" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                                            Sign Up Here
                                        </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                            </form>     



                        </div>                     
                    </div>  
        </div>
        <div id="signupbox" style="display:none; margin-top:50px" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-info">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="panel-title">Sign Up</div>
                            <div style="float:right; font-size: 85%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a id="signinlink" href="#" onclick="$('#signupbox').hide(); $('#loginbox').show()">Sign In</a></div>
                        </div>  
                        <div class="panel-body" >
                            <form id="signupform" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                
                                <div id="signupalert" style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <p>Error:</p>
                                    <span></span>
                                </div>
                                    
                                
                                  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="firstname" class="col-md-3 control-label">First Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="lastname" class="col-md-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password" class="col-md-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="passwd" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="icode" class="col-md-3 control-label">Invitation Code</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="icode" placeholder="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->                                        
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                        <button id="btn-signup" type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i> &nbsp Sign Up</button>
                                        <span style="margin-left:8px;">or</span>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div style="border-top: 1px solid #999; padding-top:20px"  class="form-group">
                                    
                                    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                        <button id="btn-fbsignup" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-facebook"></i>   Sign Up with Facebook</button>
                                    </div>                                           
                                        
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                            </form>
                         </div>
                    </div>

               
               
                
         </div> 
@endsection
```

route is default

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Console is not showing any errors and view is not showing anything.

[image]

Although the blade files are coded correctly, it is not working
when I remove asset files from , it show view .
So what wrong in asset file
[image]
Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Is that `betternet-wrapper` stuff from your `layouts.master`?

Comment: no bro , when I remove asset files, view is showing without UI feature.the problem is in asset files .How can fix it.Am I wrong in mention of this file from public folder.laravel 8 need to compile first this asset files?

Comment: No, you don't need to compile like that. Load the assets 1 by 1 and then see which asset is creating the issue. Also that `betternet` thing is not in your `master` or your `welcome`, so you need to see where that is coming from.